# How to produce this lead electro house synth?

Tags: synthesizer, vst, electronic-music

[This chorus](https://soundcloud.com/housemusic/stranger-by-stoneway) blows me away (1:01). I was wondering how to produce the lead synth that solo's at about 1:06 ?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I agree, this tune is dope! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am hearing a string like patch with a reverse envelope (slow attack, and quick release like being played backwards) through a wah wah as in a spectral glide with an arpeggiated sequence at the end of each phrase.

This setup largely depends on the gear your are using as there are numerous synths that could produce this or a combination of synth and pedals (such as a Zoom G21NU).

Comment: I would love the skill to be able to reverse engineer sounds just by listening to them!

Comment: There is more to this piece then I offered, let's not forget the player(s) have serious chops going on and bringing a ton of emotional value to the piece.